# Show notifications on lock screen of Xiaomi devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Push notifications not shows on lock screen of Xiaomi devices.

I've tried to use VISIBILITY_PUBLIC in notification builder and channel but it doesn't work.

The problem is that Xiaomi devices has special permission in apps notifications settings which permits to show notification at lock screen. But this permission is turn off by default. But in some apps like "Telegram" this permission is on by default after installation from google play, I can't find the solution how to do that.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you found solution?

Comment: same here ! any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I had a similar problem an a Huawei Device (API 29).
I wanted to use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW on my NotificationChannel, but when I was trying to send Notifications on this Huawei Device, they where not Visible on the Lock Screen.

I figured out that there is an App Notification Option on this Huawei Device to use "gentle notifications". Those Notifications are not shown on the Lock Screen and this Option is turned on by Default if your Channel uses IMPORTANCE_LOW or below.
Changing the Importance of the Channel to IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT was solving my Problem.

Since I wanted IMPORTANCE_LOW because I dont wanted an Notification Sound, I just had to do a little workaround and set setSound(null, null) and setVibrationPattern(null).

```
NotificationChannel nChannel1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
nChannel1.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
nChannel1.setSound(null, null);
nChannel1.setVibrationPattern(null);
nChannel1.setDescription("Description");
nManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
nManager.createNotificationChannel(nChannel1);
    
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .build();
nManager.notify(1, notification);
```